# Writing to Airflow Logs

Tags: airflow

One way to write to the logs in Airflow is to return a string from a PythonOperator like on line 44 [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/ff45d8f2218a8da9328161aa66d004c3db3b367e/airflow/example_dags/example_python_operator.py).

Are there other ways that allow me to write to the airflow log files? I've found that print statements are not saved to the logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding logs to Airflow Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120467/adding-logs-to-airflow-logs)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can import the logging module into your code and write to logs that way

```
import logging

logging.info('Hello')
```

Here are some more options

```
import logging    

logging.debug('This is a debug message')
logging.info('This is an info message')
logging.warning('This is a warning message')
logging.error('This is an error message')
logging.critical('This is a critical message')
```

Comment: Does this work for anything other than "info"?  I got it to work when my warning level was "info", but then I tried setting the airflow.cfg logging_level to WARNING and ERROR and tried using logging.warning('my message') and logging.error('my message'), and neither or these two things worked.  Sadly, the airflow logs are really verbose and I don't want to spam my logs with redundant information.  I prefer to just write out custom application messages with "INFO" and not get all the clutter in the log.  Not sure if this isn't supported yet or not in Airflow 1.10.1?

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why I might use logging.info over printing (for simple debugging purposes or to read information about a DAG exectution).

Comment: Good point @theStud54 - to support that, in my case, print statements end up as INFO-level log statements anyways.

Comment: My "logging.info" is not shown in the log. Print-statements are on the other hand

Answer (score 18):

You might use airflow logger

```
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger("airflow.task")
logger.error("Your custom error")
```

Comment: Where would the logs go in this case? What happens when I'm logging from an independent python script which is not connected to any DAG or Task?

Comment: You ask Airflow to provide a logger configured by Airflow by calling `logging.getLogger("airflow.task")`. Logs go to a directory specified in `airflow.cfg` file

Comment: Airflow's preconfigured logger is returned only for a process started by airflow and all threads started by the main process. It doesn't work for a new process(a new default logger is created for a new process). But it does work for a new thread started by the same process.

Answer (score 8):

There's a logger mixin class you can use:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py

```
from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin

LoggingMixin().log.info("Hello")
```

Then in airflow logs you'll see:

```
[2021-07-07 15:55:42,370] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Hello
```