# How to print a unique message in Airflow operator?

Tags: python, airflow

In airflow it's possible to write to the log with a simple `print()` or with logger as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120474/writing-to-airflow-logs)

However this won't work when trying to print inside an operator.

I have the following code:

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    gcs_export_uri_template = ["adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -params.i), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*"]
    update_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='load_ads_to_BigQuery-{}'.format(i),
        bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
        destination_project_dataset_table=table_name_template,
        source_format='CSV',
        source_objects=gcs_export_uri_template,
        schema_fields=dc(),
        params={'i': i},
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
        bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID
    )
```

Now say I want to print `"My name is load_ads_to_BigQuery-{}".format{i)`
as you can see this print is uniuqe per operator.

If I do it as:

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print("My name is load_ads_to_BigQuery-{}".format{i))
    gcs_export_uri_template = ...
    update_bigquery = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(...)
```

All 5 operators will print all 5 prints. Which is incorrect in my case.
The print must be inside the `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can also log _inside_ operators using the log method from BaseOperator like so `self.log.info("This was %s", "fun")`. Are all the print-statements done inside the dag or is your for-loop inside a custom Operator?

Comment: @judoole I'm not sure I understand

Comment: Do you print inside your dag-file, or are you doing your printing inside a selfcreated module, creating 5 `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`s in a for loop? Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: @judoole I'm not printing at all.. I want to add the print to my code. I want to print inside the GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator.

Comment: If understand correctly you would like to print something like "Uploading file bla-bla-bla to bucket blablabla" and when done "Uploaded file bla-bla-bla"?

Comment: @judoole yep. that is correct. but each `operator(i)` should show only the prints for his `i`

Comment: Aha. Sounds like something I've just done this week :) I'll try to answer with the solution I ended up with

Comment: Ups. Sorry, read that the wrong way. I have not done that before.  Might be that you can do a `gcs_export_uri_template = ["{% print 'my-name-is-" + i + "%} adstest/{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -params.i), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y/%m/%d') }}/*"]`

Comment: @judoole I'm pretty sure there is a syntax error with it...you start with `"` then close it before the 2nd `%`?

Comment: Yes, it should rather be a `'` I see. Somewhat ugly code to use string concatination, but it skips the problem with `{` being stripped with String.format. What I thought might work is to use the `%` to execute code-blocks, like https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html#templating-with-jinja

Comment: it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Bah. Thought so. The closest thing I can think of then is to either write an own Operator-class that instantiates a `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` in its `execute`-method, and does logging there. Or copy the code of `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` and edit to your own liking. Maybe a PR to Airflow would be appreciated also :)

Comment: I think this is a problem for all operators. You are suggesting that I will wrap my operator with a function that will print and then will execute the operator.. I don't think airflow support this :\ I submitted a ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-3000

Comment: No, wrap the execution and creation of `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` in an own class. I can illustrate in a solution.

Comment: @judoole I need this print in various of operators on like 20 dags :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that might suffice is to create a wrapper-class. Example:

```
class MyGoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ('bucket', 'source_objects',
                   'schema_object', 'destination_project_dataset_table')

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
          bucket,
          destination_project_dataset_table,
          source_format,
          source_objects,
          schema_fields,
          params,
          create_disposition,
          write_disposition,
          skip_leading_rows,
          google_cloud_storage_conn_id,
          bigquery_conn_id,
          *args,
          **kwargs):
     super(InfogroupFilestreamOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.bucket= bucket
     self.destination_project_dataset_table=destination_project_dataset_table
     ...

  def execute(self, context):
      self.log.info("My name is %s", self.task_id)
      hook=GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id="doesnt_matter",
            bucket=self.bucket,             
            source_format=self.source_format,
            ...
            )

     return hook.execute(context)
```

`MyGoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` can then be instantiated instead of `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` in your for-loop.

Comment: Why not `class MyGoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator): pass`, override `execute`, and call `super().execute(context)`?

Comment: Yes, that I guess would work just as well in this case. Much better solution. Feel free to edit if you'd like some extra points, or make an answer yourself. I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @judoole's answer, you could extend `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` directly.

```
class MyGoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(LoggingMixin, GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator):

    def execute(self, context):
        self.logger.info('Inside task {task_id}'.format(task_id=context['task_id']))
        super().execute(context)
```

More generally, you could write a mixin class that would automatically do this type of logging for a variety of operators.

```
class LogTaskExecutionMixin(object):

    def execute(self, context):
        self.logger.info('Inside task {task_id}'.format(task_id=context['task_id']))
        super().execute(context)

class MyGoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    LogTaskExecutionMixin, LoggingMixin, GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
):
    pass
```

The thinking in both of these approaches is that you define a new operator that writes a log message before execution but is otherwise identical to the operator that you have extended.