# Airflow duplicating logs

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow 1.10.4 and I'm facing a problem when I use logging in my custom modules.

My code be like:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info('hello there')
```

And the output be like:

```
[2020-01-22 09:44:29,954] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [[34m2020-01-22 09:44:29,954[0m] {{[34mbase_hook.py:[0m84}} INFO[0m - hello there.
```

The time, file name and logging level are duplicated in every line of my log.
How can I implement the log of Airflow to avoid this? (I used self.log in my operators and there is no problem.)

Comment: I am also having this problem... it's definitely not a log format string issue. I have tried setting up 'advanced logging' with a custom logging_config.py script, but it doesn't cover all cases (for example, logs emitted by my custom module look correct (no doubled timestamp/header) when called from within a Python Operator, but not when called from the DAG itself.)

Comment: I solve this problem by passing the log of airflow operator to methods/classes. This is my temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `log_format` value in your `airflow.cfg` file.

my default config :

```
# Log format
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the default logging format of Airflow is `[%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s`, you'll always have duplicates in the log, because e.g. the datetime is once shown in the `asctime` and once in the `message` itself. So in order to fix that, you need to change the logging format of Airflow to show only the `message`.

If you're using `docker-compose.yaml` you need to set it there like this:

```
AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOG_FORMAT: '%(message)s'
```

Otherwise you have to set it in the `airflow.cfg` as @AliNadi mentioned:

```
log_format = %%(message)s
```

Note: I had an additional issue - for me the `message` was also duplicated. The reason for that was that in the python code I was calling `logging.basicConfig()` and then additionally configuring the logger like this `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` ... The solution was to remove the `logging.basicConfig()` and leave my custom logging configuration.

Reference: [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#log-format)